# How to roll out a new Version of an ActiveX Control written in VB6

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, vb6, activex

I have to maintain an old active x control written in VB6.

As we developed some new functions for it, I now need to roll out this new version to the users. How can this be done in the least obstrusive way?

The control is embedded like this

```
<OBJECT classid="clsid:..." CODEBASE="activex/plugin/myOCX.CAB#version=1,0,0,42">
    <PARAM name="RunOnLoad" value="true"></PARAM>
    [...]
</OBJECT>
```

No, when I change the `#version` to the actual one (`1,0,0,80`), it doesn't change anything. IE still loads the old version (which I can check through a function that alerts the version of the OCX).

Only when I delete the OCX from my machine and then load the page, it prints out the new version.

Obviously, the users can't and shouldn't have to do that. So the question remains: How can I effectively *force* my users on the new version, once it's been deployed to the server?

Comment: Can you post the contents of `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{<clsid>}` with all the subkeys and values?

Comment: Can you also post the contents of .INF file (it should be inside the .CAB)?

Comment: Is it because you need to change your hash, `#`, to a question mark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As IE successfully downloads and installs the component after you delete existing version from your machine, it's all about versioning. At this point I could think of several scenarios.

#### Scenario 1: bad .INF file

Open your .CAB file. You shall see .INF file inside. Open this .INF file and locate `[<component name>.ocx]` section. Check value of `FileVersion=...`, it should be `FileVersion=1,0,0,80`. I found out that this value is *not* updated automatically if you update existing .CAB file via .BAT script previously generated by Package & Deployment Wizard.

#### Scenario 2: Test environment polluted by the build process

Another scenario I can think of is that you are testing on the same machine that you used to build new version of your control. In that case your control could be registered by the build process. Here it helps to understand [how does COM activation work anyway?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2004/10/12/241420.aspx) It is always a good idea to test on a machine other than build server though.

**Possibility 1**: build process created `AppID` named-value under `HCKR\CLSID\{clsid}` registry key

As per [KB167597](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/167597/en-us):

> In pseudo-code, here's how component download is controlled for the `<OBJECT>` tag:

```
   Check the Registry for CLSID
   If CLSID of OBJECT is NOT found in the registry
      Download OBJECT
   Else If no #Version specified in CODEBASE tag
      Use OBJECT installed on system
   Else
      Check InprocServer32 key for location of installed component
      If File version of installed component < CODEBASE #Version Tag
         Download OBJECT
```

> There are a couple of exceptions to the above sequence. If an AppID
>   key is found under the CLSID, the component is usually registered to
>   run through DCOM and is not updated. Also, an Installed Version key
>   takes precedence over the file version. This is used for Java classes
>   and non-PE (portable executable) files.

To confirm the idea, check if there is `AppID` registry value for your component on the machine you use for testing. Your users, most likely, will not have `AppID` set for the `CLSID` on their machines. That's unless your component is used in at least one more different scenario, of course. Larry Osterman has a blog post [When do you need an APPID in your COM registration?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2006/01/04/509436.aspx) Also check [this MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jigarme/archive/2007/10/09/what-is-appid.aspx) if you're unsure what `AppID` is.

How can I find out if `AppID` is set for a `CLSID`? Open registry editor `regedt32`, and check values under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{<clsid>}` key. Look for `AppId` named-value of type `REG_SZ`.

**Possibility 2**: build process altered default value of `HCKR\CLSID\{clsid}\InprocServer32` registry key

Check default value (`(Default)`) of `HCKR\CLSID\{clsid}\InprocServer32` registry key. If it points to the location you use as output of component compilation process then it, most likely, has been set during build (unless you put build results directly to `C:\WINDOWS\Downloaded Program Files` which I really doubt). OS uses this value to determine what binary to use on COM component activation. Run `regsvr32 /u <path to the .ocx created during compilation>` and re-run your test with a webpage.

---

If nothing helps, you need to investigate the issue more carefully. Fire up [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx), ask it to trace registry and file system activity for IE process, and see how IE decides (not to) update your control. Interesting information in collected traces should begin right after registry query for your control's `CLSID`.

Comment: Unfortunately no, the development machine is completely disconnected from the users and the test servers/machines.

Comment: Where can I find this AppId? The process monitor is not really helpful, I don't really know what to look for there, as there are thousands of operations that the IE does when I open the testing page.

Comment: Well, now it get's really odd... None of the two CLSIDs is registered in the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID`

Comment: @FlorianPeschka That's pretty strange. If nothing else, `HKCR\CLSID\{clsid}` key must be created when you load a webpage with the control and let IE install it. There must be .inf file inside your .cab file. Does it have `[AddToRegistry]` section? How do you generate .cab file? Frankly, I never used anything other than Package & Deployment Wizard for that.

Comment: @FlorianPeschka OK, I could think of yet another possibility and updated my post. But. I see no way your component can work without corresponding `HKCR\CLSID\{clsid}` key.

Comment: It seems I actually needed to change the CLSID completely in order for the clients to install it properly. I guess some group policiy was somehow locking it from being updated. As for XP machines, I actually had to create an MSI installer for them to even get the OCX installed. Windows7 Internet Explorer (although the exact same version as on XP) installed it from the web properly. Very strange things.

I will accept your answer as it led me on the right path, although the actual error wasn't covered by it. But I think that it's highly unlikely I'll ever know what really went wrong...

Answer (score 0):

It might be best to just break compatibility.

Open up `Project Properties` and from the `Component` tab, change `Version Compatibility` to `No Compatibility`.  Compile, and then change your `clsid` to match the new one.

Comment: I did that - so I now have a new CLSID, but the IE (on Windows XP) doesn't install it anymore. Is there a way to manually install the OCX?

Comment: @FlorianPeschka: The same way you installed the old one.  You can use regsvr32.exe.

Comment: Well, I never installed the old one. That was there for about 10 years now, never being changed. So now, noone knows how it was installed. It seems to work automatically on Windows 7 machines, they put it in the "Downloaded Files" folder, but that doesn't happen in Windows XP

Comment: @C-PoundGuru It is IE's job to register the component. The whole point of such deployment scenario is to spare a user from running any installers.